# How can I make my navigation bar scroll up and down with the scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am using the Serif WebPlus 6 to make a website, but I cannot seem to find a way to make the navigation bar to move when scrolled up and down; I am using an image on top Hotspot as a mean of navigation due to their limited navigation style options.
What I would like, is, that image to move up and down?

Thanks guys! 
Saif

Comment: Maybe this question is better asked on the Serif WebPlus 6 support forums.

Comment: Is the generated HTML for the navigation bar one element? If yes, does it have an id?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you mean having the navigation scroll down with the page making it appear fixed to a position?

Do you have access to edit the HTML and CSS of your website?

if so it is actually very easy to create a floating menu bar. The operative CSS code is

```
position:fixed;
```

for example:

```
#nav{
Position:fixed;
}
```

Create an ID and put that in with any other styling you want to use.

Assign that to a `<div>` tag in your HTML

for example:

```
<div id="nav">
link1
link2
link3
</div>
```

if you dont have access to the code and Serif doesnt offer this as a feature then I'd say you cant do it.

and indent your code unlike my examples :/

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I thought T P wanted to un-fix.

Comment: If he is trying to unfix then just do the opposite. either take that line out of the CSS or turn the feature off from the settings if there is  an option for it...if not then he wont be able to do it.

Comment: That's fab, they do offer HTML I will try your suggestion to see if that will work, will let you know how that goes!

Answer (score 0):

To create a floating navbar on WebPlus X6, you can add a panel (Insert->Panel) and choose the option to 'Align panel to browser window' to make that panel fixed (that is, it will not move when the browser window is scrolled). Then, you can place your navbar within the panel so it too does not move on scroll.